# Because my dynamic title is not displayed correctly?

Tags: javascript, title

I have a question about my JS test code. I need it to show each interval of 1500 the next character, but for some reason I do not see where they are automatically multiplied, until the browser is bugged. I share the code here:

```
<title>Minuevotitulodeprueba</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i=1;
    var LegitTitle = document.title;
    function ChangeTitle(){
        document.title = LegitTitle.substring(0,i);
        i++;
        if(i>LegitTitle.length) 
            i = 0;
        setInterval('ChangeTitle()',1500);  
    }
    ChangeTitle()
</script>
```

I am a new developer I beg for mercy xdd

Comment: issue with your code is you used setInterval when you should have use setTimeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with your code

1. The first parameter to the `setInterval` function shouldn't be a string, but a function --> `setInterval(ChangeTitle,1500);`. It would work though with the string (expression) version, but that is not recommended.
2. You shouldn't use the `setInterval` inside a function that itself is called itself in the `setInterval` unless you know what you are doing

Put it outside of the function ...

```js
var i = 1;
var LegitTitle = document.title;
function ChangeTitle(){
  document.title = LegitTitle.substring(0,i);
  i++; 
  if (i > LegitTitle.length) {
    i = 0;
  }
  console.log(document.title)
}

setInterval(ChangeTitle,1500);
```

```html
<title>Minuevotitulodeprueba</title>
```

... or alternatively use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`

```js
var i = 1;
var LegitTitle = document.title;
function ChangeTitle(){
  document.title = LegitTitle.substring(0,i);
  i++; 
  if (i > LegitTitle.length) {
    i = 0;
  }
  console.log(document.title)
  
  setTimeout(ChangeTitle, 1500);
}

ChangeTitle()
```

```html
<title>Minuevotitulodeprueba</title>
```

Comment: I was a bit surprised too, but the string actually worked too when i tried it.

Comment: Oh yeah, you can have an expression string which will be evaluated, but that should be avoided since eval ist evil

Answer (score 0):

You set a new interval each time you call the function, but the iteration calls the function on an interval not a timeout. Therefore you can avoid this problem by declaring the iteration outside of the function call.

```js
var i=1;
    var LegitTitle = document.title;
    function ChangeTitle(){
        
        document.title = LegitTitle.substring(0,i);
        
        if(i>LegitTitle.length) {
            i = 0;
        }
        console.log('i = ' + i);
        console.log('Title = ' + document.title);
        i++;
    }
    ChangeTitle();
    setInterval(ChangeTitle,1500);
```

```html
<title>Minuevotitulodeprueba</title>
```

Comment: That worked for me, but not exactly as I wanted, it shows the full title at the beginning. Just modify the position of the "i" and it seems to be displayed correctly, thank you very much experts!

Comment: @McGyver please accept the best answer so people will see that your problem is solved.

Comment: You can do a normal function call on `window.onload` to change the title immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Only issue you had is you used setInterval instead of setTimeout... Simple swap and the code works fine.

```js
var i = 1;
var LegitTitle = document.title;

function ChangeTitle() {
  document.title = LegitTitle.substring(0, i);
  console.log(document.title)
  i++;
  if (i > LegitTitle.length)
    i = 0;
  setTimeout('ChangeTitle()', 1500);
}
ChangeTitle()
```

```html
<title>Minuevotitulodeprueba</title>
```